# How to block minecart with chest until they are empty?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I got an item-transfer system.
I got a hopper under a detector rail, which detects whenever the chest is empty, but I have no way to block it.

What should I do?

Comment: How is your track set up? A single power rail that gets powered when the hopper is empty may work depending on if the hopper is at the end or middle of a line. You may also be able to use a sloping power rail to get the job done, but I'd have to test to see if that would work.

Comment: What exactly are your trying to achieve? Do you want to unload your minecart or your chest? And is your minecart going back and forth from collecting and unloading?
For a Minecart unloading you could go for something simple like place your detector rail in a sloped state, blocking the minecart on its way out with a fencegate which gets opened once your minecart is empty.
There are tons of tutorials for unloading stations online.

Answer (score 2):

You must use a **comparator** on the **hopper** (with one powered rail above it), than a redstone torch to **activate** it.

Check bellow:

[image: block-minecart_side]

[image: block-minecart_up]

What happens is that when the minecart move one item into the hopper, the **comparator** detect this and send one **energy** pulse to the repeater, that energizes a block. This guy have a redstone above it that charges a second block with a redstone torch on it, consequently **deactivating the torch** and unpowering the rail. When all items were moved to the chest, there's **no more energy**, so the redstone torch power on and **activate the rail**, forcing the **minecart** to **move** back.

**IF YOUR MINECART CAN'T GO BACK:**

The same system above, the difference is that you need a detector rail 1 block far from the hopper and the powered rail must be going down:

[image: up]

[image: side]

[image: front]

[image: down_side]

Comment: Yay but I can't let the minecart go and go on the other side

Comment: *I can't let the minecart move back

Comment: I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Take a look, @InforMatheMusic